# Is this projector capable of 1080i resolution?

Tags: specifications, projector

From the specs of the projector:

> DLP - 4000 lumen - 1024 x 768 - 480p - 720p - 1080i - 3D Ready - 6.4 pounds

They state the resolution is 1024x768, but then they add 1080i, from wikipedia:

> The term 1080i assumes a widescreen aspect ratio of 16:9, implying a
>   frame size of 1920×1080 pixels.

I'm a bit confused, what the resolution of this projector?

Comment: This question is not exactly on topic here on this site which is about Audio and Video **Production**, but since projectors are used in some performance scenarios, I've edited it to more closely fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes

Most projectors support multiple resolutions.  The specifications list all resolutions supported by the projector.

The projector you are asking about will handle 1024x768, 480p, 720p, and 1080i.

Comment: OK, so you changed a little bit the question title. What I meant to ask was: is 1080i similar to 1080X1920 ?

Comment: Yes.  [1080i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080i) refers to a standard resolution which is indeed 1080x1920.